# C# new Form return Value not recognised by Mainform

Tags: c#, .net, forms, variables, toolstrip

I open an additional form through a Toolstrip to enter a Username that will be needed in the Mainform (and is declared as String in the Mainform)

Code of Mainform:

```
private void toolStripButton6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Form frm = new Form3())
        {
            frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
            frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;

            if (frm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Username = frm.ReturnValue1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Code of Form3:

```
    public string ReturnValue1 { 
        get
        {
            return textBox1.Text;
        }
    } 
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

C# tells me that there is no frm.ReturnValue1 :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have declared your form as type `Form` not `Form3`:

```
using (Form frm = new Form3())
```

and as the class `Form` doesn't have a property `ReturnValue1` you are getting the error. This compiles because `Form3` is a subclass of `Form` so you can assign it to a variable of type `Form` without any casting being required. If you had it the other way round the compiler would have told you you needed a cast.

Your code should be:

```
using (Form3 frm = new Form3())
```

or perhaps even (my preference):

```
using (var frm = new Form3())
```

Then it will always be of the right type and you don't have to remember to change the class name in two places should you decide to use a different form in future.

Comment: And don't name your forms "Form1" and "Form2" and "Form3".  How about "MainForm" or "EmployeeAddEditForm", something meaningful.

Comment: @granadaCoder - well yes, but I'm using the same names as the OP here.

Comment: Sorry, I was talking to the OP, not you.  I think he/she would have "seen" the error earlier with meaningful names.

Comment: @granadaCoder - quite possibly.